# Is there a way to find the physical address of a global variable from the user space

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

Lets say I have a global variable defined in my program. I want to know its physical address (not virtual address). Is there a way to find it in Linux in user space? I know that the physical address might change during execution, but I am OK with just knowing the current physical address.

Comment: That ^^ is the first Google hit, literally.

Comment: Why do you ask? From the application point of view, the physical RAM address does not matter at all (since the application don't see it).

Answer (score 0):

`virt_to_phys` is available but can only be used in `kernel` space and not in user space, specifically when is allocated with `kmalloc` and only when it is in page tables.

http://mirror.linux.org.au/linux-mandocs/2.6.12.4/virt_to_phys.html

Comment: I believe there's a way to do it with the information in `/proc`...